# Change the admin user for a Trello organization?

Tags: trello, trello-organization, user-accounts

How would I go about changing the administrator user to someone else? Recently the person who signed up our organization for Trello left. We are trying to reach them to see if they can transfer the admin rights to another user that is still with the organization but no success so far.

Comment: Contact support@trello.com