# How do you remove/close a board if the creator has left your organization in Trello?

Tags: trello

Is there a concept of an "admin" for a board that can close it?

Comment: I have the same question!

Comment: Related issue: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/36741/change-the-admin-user-for-a-trello-organization

Answer (score 1):

As the linked answers have pointed out, contact support@trello.com.